# Where is the database SERVICE NAME defined and what is the proper method for changing it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm researching the connection methods for an Oracle 12c database and I understand the difference between an SID and Service Name, but I cannot figure out where the service name is defined or how to change it.

Presumably it was named the same as the SID I typed in during installation, but can it be changed post-installation?  Is there a configuration file where that is done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using dynamic registration? If so, you might want to verify the values of your service_names and local_listener parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Understanding Database Services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netag/identifying-and-accessing-database.html#GUID-153861C1-16AD-41EC-A179-074146B722E6)

> The service name defaults to the global database name, a name
>   comprising the database name (DB_NAME initialization parameter) and
>   domain name (DB_DOMAIN initialization parameter).

You can find service information in [ALL_SERVICES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_SERVICES.html).

You can manage services with [DBMS_SERVICE.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SERVICE.html)

In an Oracle Restart or clustered environment, you can manage services with [srvctl](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/racad/server-control-utility-reference.html#GUID-C2D37BAB-DA98-49B4-A777-F2B3AA8D2E7A), which uses `DBMS_SERVICE` in the background.

No, you should not use the `service_names` parameter. That should be left to maintained by the above.

The default services should not be used by clients, and you should always create your own service(s) with the required properties.

[Default Service Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/racad/workload-management-with-dynamic-database-services.html#GUID-599AD3C2-6E55-4124-A7A5-094DA2593D50)

> Your Oracle RAC database includes an Oracle database service
>   identified by DB_UNIQUE_NAME, if set, or DB_NAME or PDB_NAME, if not.
>   This default service is always available on all instances in an Oracle
>   RAC environment, unless an instance is in restricted mode. You cannot
>   alter this service or its properties. Additionally, the database
>   supports the following two internal services:
>
> SYS$BACKGROUND is used by the background processes only
>
> SYS$USERS is the default service for user sessions that are not
>   associated with any application service
>
> All of these services are used for internal management. You cannot
>   stop or disable any of these internal services to do planned outages
>   or to failover to Oracle Data Guard. Do not use these services for
>   client connections.

The above is about RAC from the RAC documentation, but it is true for single instance environments as well.

Comment: Why is using the service_names parameter unacceptable for non-rac environments? (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/SERVICE_NAMES.html#GUID-AC956707-D568-4F8A-BF2E-99BA41E0A64F)

Comment: @JohnA It is not unacceptable. If all you need a service for is to have a separately named entry point for connections, `service_names` can do that. You will be able to analyze performance separately for clients using different services, and you can use it with Resource Manager to prioritize workload based on services. But if you want to create a role based service in a Data Guard environment, or use database editions for zero downtime application patching, or use the high availability features of a service, then `service_names` parameter alone is not enough.

Comment: I agree with everything you are saying, but stating "No, you should not use the service_names parameter", implies that it's an incorrect thing to do. Like you said above, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.